# NoClassDefFoundError kotlinx serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, json-serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I have a kotlin multiplatform project and I need to `serialize` a class. I have included the following dependency in my `commonMain` and `androidMain` and `iosMain` respectively in my `multiplatform gradle file`:

```
 //commonMain
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.20.0"

 //androidMain
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.20.0"

 //iosMain
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:0.20.0"
```

This is the class I want to `serialize`:

```
@Serializable
class Test {

    fun toJsonTestClass() = Json.stringify(Test.serializer(), this)
    var value1:Double = 0.toDouble()
       
    companion object {

        fun buildClass(value1 : Double):Test {

            val test = Test()
            test.value1 = value1
   
            return test
        }

         fun fromJsonTestClass(json:String) = Json.parse(Test.serializer(), json)
    }
}
```

And in another class (`TrialClass`), this is how I am testing it:

```
val test = Test()
val testToJson = test.toJsonTestClass() //<- This is where the error is pointing to.

println(testToJson)
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/serialization/json/Json
>   at Test.toJsonTestClass(Test.kt:28)
>   at TrialClass.main(TrialClass.kt:4)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
> ```

I get no issues when having the imports in my class, but when running I get the above mentioned error.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is probably being obfuscated. You have two options:

Add the [`@Keep`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/Keep) annotation above the class:

```
@Serializable
@Keep
class Teste {
// ...
}...
```

or add it to your module's proguard:

```
-keep (path_to_the_class).test.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not the best at proguard, so I want to use the `Keep` annotation, but for some reason, I can't find it in Kotlin Multiplatform. Is there a specific library I have to include?

Comment: I don't think so, but you have to `import androidx.annotation.Keep`.

Comment: Understood. I couldn't even `import androidx.annotation.Keep`. So instead I went with the proguard way, and it worked. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Tip: Try to migrate your project to AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Just a quick question, since my class is in the `commonMain` package, I can't make use of the ` @Keep` annotation, do you know if there is anything similar to that keep annotation?

Comment: I've already seen some people making an `interface`, adding it to proguard, and whenever you need some class or enum to not be obfuscated, you make them implement that interface. But migrating to androidx is really a good deal :)

Comment: Awesome, sounds good. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I did everything right - code & configuration.  And `gradle clean` didn't help, I ended up with the magic `Invalidate Caches / Restart` from IntelliJ IDEA.